# PHP Search erro

Tags: php, mysql

Faço a pesquisa com o numMec existente e aparece me que não existe na base de dados

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#i","",$searchq);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bombeiros WHERE numMec = '%$searchq%'") or die("Nao consegue pesquisar");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count==0){
    $output='<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable fade-in">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                <strong>Bombeiro</strong> não existe na base de dados.
            </div>';
}else{
    $nome=$row_bombs['Nome'];
    $num=$row_bombs['numMec'];

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $output='<div class="col-sm mx-auto" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 300px;">
                        <img class="mx-auto card-img-top" src="img/BVMCN.png" style="width: 50%; padding-top: 10px;"></br>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"> '.$nome.'</h5>
                            <a href="bombeiro.php?id="'.$num.' class="btn btn-primary col-sm">'.$num.'</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
    }
}
}
?>
<?php print("$output");?>
```

e este no fim  da me um erro(Notice: Undefined variable: output)

Comment: Porque você colocou `numMec = '%$searchq%'"`, ao invés de igual não seria like? Provavelmente sua consulta está errada.

Comment: mas eu quero que seja o mesmo resultado e nao parecido

Comment: porque se eu colocar like nao aparece o numero que procurei mas sim outro

Comment: O que vem em `$_POST['search']` ? Qual o tipo de `numMec` na tabela `bombeiros` ?

Comment: sao numeros ao todo 8  e esta como int

Comment: Então pra que o simbolo de percentual se não irá buscar utilizando o `like`? Ao fazer `numMec = '%$searchq%'`, você está fazendo o sql entender `numMec = '%12345678%'`, por isso não trará nenhum resultado. Ou retire o `%` ou use o `like` ao invés de `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No início do seu código adicione ela assim: `$output = '';`

O erro que tinha aparecido estava notificando que sua variável não existia porque ela só era setada no `if(){}` então por isso que pedi que você escrevesse ela no inicio com o valor vazio ou `null`, agora a respeito da sua pesquisa é bem simples a sua `$query` está errada olhe o exemplo abaixo.

Atual:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bombeiros WHERE numMec = '%$searchq%'") or die("Nao consegue pesquisar");
```

Atualize por está:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bombeiros WHERE numMec = nome da coluna LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Nao consegue pesquisar");
```

Teste que agora vai funcionar.

Comment: Diz que não existe o que procurei

Comment: tenho 5 de momento

Comment: tente assim: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bombeiros WHERE numMec = '$searchq'") or die("Nao consegue pesquisar");

Comment: Assim aparece me um mas não o que eu pesquisei

Comment: Tente assim: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bombeiros WHERE numMec like ='$searchq' '') or die("Nao consegue pesquisar");

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIO0F.png

Comment: Nao consegue pesquisar com o LIKE =

Comment: Anoite quando chegar em casa eu vou te responder melhor.

Comment: já consegui resolver

Comment: Como ficou seu código?

Comment: Tive que alterar um outro código antes que era o que fazia dar o conflito

Comment: Show o importante que conseguiu fazer funcionar.

Answer (score -2):

No início do seu código adicione ela assim: `$output = '';`

Comment: a NOTICE ja desapareceu mas nao me faz a pesquisa